# Define Python type hints in for-loop inside class body

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, type-hinting

I have the following code in Python:

```
class ModuleA:
    """This is a reusable element to compose larger designs with"""


class ModuleB:
    """Another reusable element"""


class MyDesign:
    a: ModuleA
    b0: ModuleB
    b1: ModuleB
    b2: ModuleB
```

The type hints are used upon instantiation of `MyDesign` to dynamically add instances of the various Modules. I chose this syntax because the class `MyDesign` is really just a "template" defining what Modules it's composed of, but the instantiation of modules needs some arguments only available when `MyDesign` is being instantiated.

I would like to simplify the definition of `MyDesign` into something like

```
class MyDesign:
    a: ModuleA


# define repetitive patterns in a loop
for i in range(2):
    MyDesign.__type_hints__[f"b{i}"] = ModuleB
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why ``b0``, ``b1``, ... are not just a *single* ``b: List[ModuleB]``?

Comment: The point of *static* type annotations is that they are, well, static so creating them dynamically is usually not sensible. Do you actually need them statically verified or do you *just* use them for their runtime existence? Can you perhaps give a more concrete example that makes it apparent why static definitions are not appropriate?

Comment: This example (https://github.com/pypga/pypga/blob/master/README.rst#usage - see e definition of `EightLeds`) is my actual use-case. The type-hints are used as a way to specify how the objects are built, rather than for verification of existing objects.

Comment: I could use `b: List[ModuleB]`, though since I use this syntax to specify the object I would need a way to also fix the length of the `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is to dynamically modify the type hints in a class.
You can achieve that by modifying the annotations__ property of the class like so:

```
from typing import get_type_hints

class ModuleA:
    """This is a reusable element to compose larger designs with"""


class ModuleB:
    """Another reusable element"""


class MyDesign:
    a: ModuleA
    b0: ModuleA
    b1: ModuleA
    b2: ModuleA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_type_hints(MyDesign))
    for i in range(2):
        MyDesign.__annotations__[f"b{i}"] = ModuleB

    print(get_type_hints(MyDesign))
```

result of running this code:

```
{'a': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>, 'b0': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>, 'b1': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>, 'b2': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>}
{'a': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>, 'b0': <class '__main__.ModuleB'>, 'b1': <class '__main__.ModuleB'>, 'b2': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>}
```

if you want to add the class members dynamically you can use this code:

```
for i in range(2):
    MyDesign.a = lambda: None
    setattr(MyDesign.a, f"b{i}", None)
    MyDesign.__annotations__[f"b{i}"] = ModuleB
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that modifying ``__annotations__`` changes the *runtime* definition of the type. A *static* type checker will not be aware of this.

Comment: The last loop looks wrong. The ``MyDesign.a = ..`` should not be in the loop and the ``setattr`` should be ``setattr(MyDesign, f"b{i}", ...)``.

Comment: Thanks, the `__annotations__` attribute is what I needed. It showed me how to solve my problem in an even better way (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following also works, which is even closer to what I want, as it is adds the type annotation from a loop inside the class definition, so even static type checkers should be able to work with this.

```
from typing import get_type_hints


class ModuleA:
    """This is a reusable element to compose larger designs with"""


class ModuleB:
    """Another reusable element"""


class MyDesign:
    a: ModuleA
    
    for i in range(3):
        __annotations__[f"b{i}"] = ModuleB

        
print(get_type_hints(MyDesign))
```

The print-statement yields

```
{'a': <class '__main__.ModuleA'>, 'b0': <class '__main__.ModuleB'>, 'b1': <class '__main__.ModuleB'>, 'b2': <class '__main__.ModuleB'>}
```